# Access level user For Buttons in the forms

Tags: asp.net

I Want Set Access level user For Buttons in the forms. example in the each form i have Add , Edit ,search and Delete button and I want user1 access to delete and update button in the form 1 and user 2 access to all buttons in each forms.

i create Table for Save Forms Name  and Create other Table for Save User Profile and create table for save access User to forms and button. But I do not know how these settings in the form.
In any form is when you load the data read from the database?And to apply settings or Can I do this, write a general function,That automatically does this for every form????

thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following link was of great help when I encountered the same problem (it is for asp.net 2.0 but applies to the newer versions):

[Recipe: Implementing Role-Based Security with ASP.NET 2.0 using Windows Authentication and SQL Server](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server.aspx)

SO in few words, you need to set up the Roles and then use them to enable access to users according to their roles. Enabling buttons and disabling buttons in a form can happen in the code behind utilizing the Roles.

For example you can use this piece of code if you have setup a role called Administrators:

```
If User.IsInRole("Administrators") Then
     'Do something only admins are allowed to-do
End If
```

I hope that this is helpfull.